# Fixing broken apt **without** destroying my system via "apt autoremove"

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

Somehow, my `apt` system got hosed on my Ubuntu 20.04.4 system, and now there are more than 1,800 packages that are marked as needing to be uninstalled.

This is from the `Xubuntu` installation, which means I'm running the `xfce` desktop.

I know that the recommended way to fix this kind of `apt` problem is to do an `apt autoremove` followed by reinstalls of the packages. However, if I do that, my system will then be totally unusable after the `apt autoremove`, due to the fact that most of my system's packages will have been uninstalled.

I'm looking for an alternative way to fix my `apt` database so that I don't have to destroy my system with the `apt autoremove` command in order to correct `apt`.

In order to illustrate the state of `apt` on my system, here are some of the things I have run ...

```
% sudo apt-get install -f
[returns a list of the names of the 1,800 packages]

% sudo dpkg configure -a
[no output]

% sudo aptitude search ?broken
[no output]

% sudo cat /var/log/apt/history.log
Start-Date: 2022-05-04  18:01:54
Requested-By: [MYUSERID] (1000)
Upgrade: networkd-dispatcher:amd64 (2.1-2~ubuntu20.04.2, 2.1-2~ubuntu20.04.3), libvirt-daemon-system-systemd:amd64 (6.0.0-0ubuntu8.15, 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.16), openssl:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13), librbd1:amd64 (15.2.14-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 15.2.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), google-chrome-stable:amd64 (101.0.4951.41-1, 101.0.4951.54-1), libvirt-clients:amd64 (6.0.0-0ubuntu8.15, 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.16), iio-sensor-proxy:amd64 (2.8-1ubuntu1, 2.8-1ubuntu2), libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd:amd64 (6.0.0-0ubuntu8.15, 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.16), libpq5:amd64 (12.9-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 12.10-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), ubuntu-drivers-common:amd64 (1:0.9.0~0.20.04.6, 1:0.9.0~0.20.04.7), libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu:amd64 (6.0.0-0ubuntu8.15, 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.16), libvirt-daemon-system:amd64 (6.0.0-0ubuntu8.15, 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.16), libssl-dev:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13), libssl-doc:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13), libmysqlclient21:amd64 (8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3, 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), libmysqlclient21:i386 (8.0.28-0ubuntu0.20.04.3, 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.2), libvirt0:amd64 (6.0.0-0ubuntu8.15, 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.16), lm-sensors:amd64 (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1, 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1.1), libsensors-config:amd64 (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1, 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1.1), libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13), libssl1.1:i386 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12, 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.13), libsensors5:amd64 (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1, 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1.1), libsensors5:i386 (1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1, 1:3.6.0-2ubuntu1.1), librados2:amd64 (15.2.14-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 15.2.16-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libvirt-daemon:amd64 (6.0.0-0ubuntu8.15, 6.0.0-0ubuntu8.16)
End-Date: 2022-05-04  18:02:47

% sudo ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3280 Jan 19 17:24 /etc/apt/sources.list
[note that the file hasn't changed in a few months]

% sudo ls -l /etc/apt/sources.list.d 
total 16
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190 Jan 19 17:24 google-chrome.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 190 Jan 19 17:24 google-chrome.list.save
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  56 Apr 14 11:06 skype-stable.list
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  56 Jan 19 17:24 skype-stable.list.save
[note that none of this has changed recently]

% sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                             
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                            
Hit:3 http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                         
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [108 kB]                                                                          
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                          
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                             
Hit:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                 
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [278 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [391 kB]      
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [940 B]                     
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [9,568 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [30.8 kB]
Hit:13 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                              
Get:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [40.6 kB]
Get:15 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [66.3 kB]
Get:16 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [2,464 B]
Fetched 1,155 kB in 2s (555 kB/s)                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

% sudo grep -r "^deb" /etc/apt/ --include=*.list
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d.save/alex-p-ubuntu-aegisub-focal.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/alex-p/aegisub/ubuntu focal main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d.save/teamviewer.list:deb https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse
/etc/apt/sources.list:deb http://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/ focal main
```

I had a similar problem in the past which I fixed as described in the "Answers" section of the following post: [apt forgot about more than 1,000 packages, and I'm unable to reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354491/apt-forgot-about-more-than-1-000-packages-and-im-unable-to-reinstall) ... it's the Answer which begins with "I figured out how to fix this problem ..."

However, this seems like a hack-y way to fix this, and I'm not sure how reliable it will be if I run it now.

Can anyone suggest any other way to fix this problem without `sudo apt autoremove` and without that hack-y method that I used in the past?

Thank you very much in advance.

**PS**: I take daily backups of my system. Are there perhaps any files or directories I can restore from my latest backup which would contain the non-broken versions of the `apt` database?

**PPS**: I tried installing `xubuntu-desktop` as discussed in the comments below. Sadly, it didn't help ...

```
% sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
xubuntu-desktop is already the newest version (2.233).
xubuntu-desktop set to manually installed.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
[list of 1,800 package names, followed by ...]
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

And all those packages remain marked as requiring uninstallation.

Comment: Apt will autoremove packages that are not, at some level,  dependencies of a manually-specified package. If you don't want your whole desktop stack removed, then simply specify that you want the `ubuntu-desktop` package installed. One easy way is `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I'm running the xfce-4 desktop manager. Would the `ubuntu-desktop` installation break that?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that. I apologize. I'll fix the original message. So, I need to find the package which would be the alternative to `ubuntu-desktop` in the xfce-4 world. The installation is "xubuntu", so I guess it would be the `xubuntu-desktop` package.

Comment: See the PPS above that I will be posting in a couple minutes to see what happened when trying to reinstall `xubuntu-desktop`. It didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem.

After reinstalling `xubuntu-desktop` and `xubuntu-core`, my problem persisted. Therefore, I assume that the problem is not due to simply one missing installation at the top of the dependency tree, but rather, that the entire `apt` database had probably somehow gotten corrupted.

So, I gave up on shortcuts, I crossed my fingers, and I ended up biting the bullet and doing a slight variation of what I did in the past, as described in my Answer here: [apt forgot about more than 1,000 packages, and I'm unable to reinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1354491/apt-forgot-about-more-than-1-000-packages-and-im-unable-to-reinstall)

This time, I only did the install of each package, not the initial remove before each install, and it worked. Here are the steps I took ...

**Step 1:**

```
% sudo apt-get install -f >apt-installs
```

After running this, the `apt-installs` file contained this data ...

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
[names of more than 1,800 packages]
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
```

**Step 2:**

I edited this `apt-installs` file to remove the top 4 lines and the bottom 2 lines, and I reformatted it so that there is one package name per line.

**Step 3:**

I prepended the string `fixit`  to the beginning of each line.

**Step 4:**

I created a shell function called `fixit` to install the specified package, and I put that function at the top of the `apt-installs` file. Now, here's what the first dozen or so lines of `apt-installs` look like ...

```
fixit() {
  [[ $# -lt 1 ]] && return 0
  package="${1}"
  shift
  echo "### fixing ${package}"
  apt-get -y install "${package}"
  echo ''
}
fixit accerciser
fixit accountsservice
fixit acpi-support
fixit acpid
fixit adb
[more than 1,800 similar lines]
```

**Step 5:**

I ran this:

```
% sudo bash apt-installs
```

This ran for around 30 minutes and reinstalled each of the packages. As can be seen in the `fixit` function, no `remove` was done before each `install`.

**Step 6:**

I then ran these two commands ...

```
% sudo apt-get purge aptitude
% sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

This got `aptitude` back in sync with the `apt` database.

Everything seems back to normal now.

I'm guessing that if I knew what `apt`-related files/directories to reinstall from my recent backup, I could have fixed the problem that way, as well. However, I don't know enough about the lower-level internals of `apt`, and I couldn't quickly figure out what items would need to be restored.

For future reference, I'd like to know this information about how to restore the `apt` database, because it will make it easier to fix this kind of problem if it occurs again.

And many thanks to **user535733**!

Comment: FYI: An even easier method is to use `sudo apt-mark manual package1 package2 package3 packageN`.

Comment: Thank you! If this ever happens again, I'll try the "apt-mark manual ..." procedure instead of the "apt-get -y install ..." procedure.

Comment: Egad. One hopes it never happens again. Lot of folks make the mistake of uninstalling their desktop metapackage *once*. Never again.

Comment: Just checking back here. In my case, I never uninstalled any desktop metapackage. The Xubuntu installation never installed such a metapackage, as far as I remember. My apt database got hosed for some other unknown reason. Also, I had a similar problem recently on a different system (Debian-11, server, no desktop), and "apt-mark manual" didn't fix the problem. I needed to do "apt-get -y install" for each package that needed to be repaired.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the the flag --no-remove. (i.e. apt-get install --fix-broken --no-remove) Or indeed `apt-get install --fix-broken --trivial-only`. See: https://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get