# apt: what directories should I back up in order to protect my "apt" configuration?

Tags: apt, package-management, backup

I'm currently running `Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS`.

Four times over the past year or two, my `apt` database got screwed up somehow (I don't know how), and the next time I ran `apt`, `apt-get`, and `aptitude`, I was told that I have more than 1,000 packages that are set up to be removed. If I did an `autoremove` with the intention of later trying to reinstall, my entire system would have become unusable, because most of the normal, everyday programs would then have been removed during that `autoremove`.

I did ***not*** (!!!) delete the top-level desktop package, nor any top-level package. This error occurred due to something (??? I don't know what) which somehow damaged the integrity of the `apt` databases on my machine.

I was able to fix this each time by going through the procedure which I have outlined in the "Answer" to this question: [Fixing broken apt **without** destroying my system via "apt autoremove"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406681/fixing-broken-apt-without-destroying-my-system-via-apt-autoremove)

However, the fact that this has occurred multiple times means that whatever caused this might cause it to happen again. In order to help fix this situation if/when it happens again, I'd like to know the following ...

What directories on my system should I back up if I want to preserve the state of the entire `apt` system at any given time? I want to take periodic backups of all of these `apt`-related directories, so that next time this error occurs, I could quickly restore my `apt` environment by restoring all of these directories to their last backed-up versions.

Thank you for any pointers and suggestions as to what directories I should back up in order to preserve the integrity of my entire `apt` environment.

Comment: I wonder what you are doing that causes this? It seems to have happened to you two times or so. I have multiple machines running for almost a decade now and have never experienced it.

Comment: I'm guessing that it might be related to `aptitude`, since I use it for most of my `apt`-related tasks. Occasionally, `aptitude` hangs and crashes, perhaps due to intermittent network glitches during the time that it's running. I wonder if an `aptitude` crash at the wrong moment might somehow end up corrupting the `apt` database. In any case, if I could find out what are all of the directories which comprise this `apt` database, I could back them up and restore them whenever this might occur in the future.

Comment: PS: I discovered `/var/lib/dpkg`. Could that be the only directory tree that I would need to back up and restore? I think there might be other package information somewhere else which `aptitude` uses, but I don't know where.

Comment: You might find [this post](https://askubuntu.com/q/1414284/968501) useful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm pretty sure that I found and tried that in the past when I encountered this problem, and something about it didn't work. I don't recall what. That is part of the reason for why I want to know how to restore the `apt` database, rather than try to use `apt`-based or `dpkg`-based utilities to fix a broken `apt` database. Those utilities are likely to also depend on the contents of this database, and if it's hosed, the utilities could also fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that `/var/lib/dpkg` is probably the directory tree that I should back up and restore.

But that's specifically for `apt` and `dpkg`, and it doesn't necessarily contain everything that `aptitude` uses, since `aptitude` is a newer utility which built upon `apt`.

I'll treat this as a provisional answer until I find out more about the database in which `aptitude` stores its own data.

**UPDATE**

I now see the following files: `/etc/cron.daily/dpkg` and `/etc/cron.daily/aptitude`. These do the backups of the `dpkg` database and the `aptitude` database, respectively.

So, my work is already being done by the OS, and if my `apt` environment ever gets hosed again, I believe that I can restore it by restoring from those backups.

Onward!

Comment: `aptitude` is not "a newer utility".

Comment: OK, but nonetheless, `aptitude` is built on top of `apt`, and it has its own database, separate from `/var/lib/dpkg`.

Also, I discovered that the backups I need are already being done. See the **UPDATE** in my answer, above.

Answer (score 0):

I have part of the answer. Install [TimeShift](https://teejeetech.com/timeshift/)

It takes snapshot of your system and lets you restore to previous state. I like it cause you can create a daily schedule and set how many days of restore to retain. 'Set it and forget it'

Let us know if this helped and a good enough solution.

apt-clone seems to be one option or

[How to backup settings and list of installed packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages)

here is a little info off the page, but lots of other ideas

> So all together as a pseudo-bash script (possible one-liner version)
>
> This assumes there is only one user on the machine (remove /'whoami'
> otherwise) and that you used the same username on both installs
> (modify dest. of rsync otherwise).
>
> dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list && sudo cp -R
> /etc/apt/sources.list* ~/ && sudo apt-key exportall > ~/Repo.keys && rsync --progress /home/`whoami` /path/to/user/profile/backup/here
>
> ### Reinstall now
>
> rsync --progress /path/to/user/profile/backup/here /home/`whoami` && sudo apt-key add ~/Repo.keys && sudo cp -R ~/sources.list* /etc/apt/ && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install dselect && sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list && sudo dselect

Comment: Thank you very much. `TimeShift` indeed looks like a useful utility. However, it turns out that three of my servers are managed at Linode and daily system backups are already being performed. I can always restore from those daily backups, but it's a time-consuming process. My other server is at home, and I do my own daily backups which also can be restored.  But what I'm trying to do is a more targeted restore of ***only*** the `apt` database, instead of the entire system. That's why I want to know what specific directories that are used by `apt` would need to be backed up and restored.